# Most efficient way of checking whether a string is present in another column's values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I have a pandas dataframe as follows,

| id | all_items | items_check1 | items_check2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1239 | 'foobar,foo,foofoo,bar' | 'foo,bar' | 'foobar' |
| 3298 | 'foobar,foo' | 'foobar' | 'bar' |
| 9384 | 'foo,bar' | 'bar,foo' | 'bar' |

I want to check if items in `items_check1` are present in `all_items` or not, and later save this result into a separate column as `check1_output`; and then want to repeat the same process again with `items_check2` and `all_items`; and save it into `check2_output`.

So the [desired output] should look like this,

| id | all_items | items_check1 | items_check2 | check1_output | check2_output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1239 | 'foobar,foo,foofoo,bar' | 'foo,bar' | 'foobar' | True | True |
| 3298 | 'foobar,foo' | 'foobar' | 'bar' | True | False |
| 9384 | 'foo,bar' | 'bar,foo' | 'bar' | True | True |

I have billions of rows and sometimes the number of items in a single cell of `all_items` can go upto 100 items. I'm looking for the most efficient way of having this comparison done.

**Attempts so far**
Following is what I have tried, this was more efficient compared to iterating over rows but I soon figured the output is not always as expected. What could be the possible reason for such a behaviour?

```py
df['check1_output'] = np.where([x[0] in x[1] for x in zip(df['items_check1'], df['all_items'])], True, False)
df['check2_output'] = np.where([x[0] in x[1] for x in zip(df['items_check2'], df['all_items'])], True, False)
```

[ actual output ]

| id | all_items | items_check1 | items_check2 | check1_output | check2_output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1239 | 'foobar,foo,foofoo,bar' | 'foo,bar' | 'foobar' | True | True |
| 3298 | 'foobar,foo' | 'foobar' | 'bar' | True | True |
| 9384 | 'foo,bar' | 'bar,foo' | 'bar' | False | True |

Here's the snippet to re-produce the above dataframe

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1239,3298,9384], 
                   'all_items': ['foobar,foo,foofoo,bar','foobar,foo','foo,bar'],
                   'items_check1': ['foo,bar','foobar','barfoo'],
                   'items_check2': ['foobar','bar','bar']
                  })
```

**EDIT:** *adding computation time*

The approach I mentioned takes, `610µs` time for a 3 row dataframe. But when I run it across the actual data with billions of records, it takes many hours. Hence looking for a much more efficient approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `issubset()` with `str.split()`:

```
df["check1_output"] = df.apply(lambda x: set(x["items_check1"].split(",")).issubset(x["all_items"].split(",")), axis=1)
df["check2_output"] = df.apply(lambda x: set(x["items_check2"].split(",")).issubset(x["all_items"].split(",")), axis=1)
>>> df
     id              all_items  ... check1_output check2_output
0  1239  foobar,foo,foofoo,bar  ...          True          True
1  3298             foobar,foo  ...          True         False
2  9384                foo,bar  ...         False          True
```

Comment: this one works, but its not as computationally efficient as the approach I already mentioned. This one takes `2.39ms` just for a 3 row dataframe, whereas doing something like a regular comparison with `in` operator after using `zip` on two constant values, only takes `610µs` time for a 3 row dataframe.

Comment: accepting this to close the question

Answer (score 1):

Numpy where will be fast

```py
import numpy as np 

…

df['check1_output'] = np.where(df['items_check1'].isin(df['all_items']), True, False)

# do same for the other check
```

Comment: doesn't give you the desired output. I'd suggest doing a dry run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` to transform a string to a list and then apply `np.in1d` to check if specific items are in all_items.

```
df['check1_output'] = df.apply(lambda row: np.in1d(row['items_check1'].split(','), row['all_items'].split(',')).all(), axis=1)
df['check2_output'] = df.apply(lambda row: np.in1d(row['items_check2'].split(','), row['all_items'].split(',')).all(), axis=1)
```